# Mozilla opens youtube video in flash player

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, youtube, flash

In my web app I have to embedd youtube videos, for that I am using iframe. it works properly in chrome in html5 player. but when I am trying in mozilla firefox the video plays in flash player. how do I force mozilla to open the video in html player. I'm using mozilla version 36. please help me.

code used ::

```
    <iframe type="text/html" width="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/videoLink">
                                                        You are using an outdated browser ! please upgrade
   </iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Youtube's JS picks the version it thinks is right for you. The decision is made based on various factors, one that might be relevant is that although Firefox supports the VIDEO element it does not (yet) support the so-called Media Source Extension functionality. I have no idea if that's why YouTube chooses to use Flash rather than a VIDEO element, but it may be one of the factors.